# how do I update a single value of an item in session storage

Tags: javascript, angular, session-storage

I have a `SessionStorage` item set with the following values:

```
    key : state-allRequestsandResponses
    value : "{"first":30,"rows":10,"sortField":"isWorkComplete","sortOrder":1}"
```

I want to obtain the value for first for example and change the value of 30 to say 40.

I'm having real difficulty with using `sessionStorage.setItem` to change this value. Can anybody give an example of how to change this value.

Comment: you need to get the whole string then write it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below method in order to store, get the data and update

```js
let data = {"first":30,"rows":10,"sortField":"isWorkComplete","sortOrder":1}

//storing the data for the first time
sessionStorage.setItem("state-allRequestsandResponses", JSON.stringify(data));
```

In order to update the data in `sessionStorage` get the object and parse it as json object since `sessionStorage` will store the data as strings.

```js
//Get the object and parse it
data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("state-allRequestsandResponses"))
data.first = 40;

sessionStorage.setItem("state-allRequestsandResponses", JSON.stringify(data));

//Verify whether the data updated in sessionStorage
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("state-allRequestsandResponses"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Once we get the value from sessionStorage, we need convert it into JSON in order to use it as a normal object.

try to do some changes like below..

```
const modifiedValue =  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('state-allRequestsandResponses'));
modifiedValue.first(40);

sessionStorage.setItem('state-allRequestsandResponses',  JSON.stringify(modifiedValue));
```

Hope this helps.. :)